# Checkbox click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a group of checkboxes inside a table where I want to change the value of a different column in the row when the checkbox is checked. I have researched for a solution but nothing I have found seems to solve my problem. I realize that my stumbling block is my unfamiliarity with jquery so any suggestions would help. Ultimately I wish to total the columns where the change has occurred to get a total. So if an answer included ideas about that as well I would not complain. Thanks as always, you are a great group.

```
  HTML

    <tr>
        <td><input name="amputeeGolfer" type="checkbox" id="amputeeGolfer" value="amputee" onchange="changeFee"/>
            <label for="amputeeGolfer">Amputee Golfer</label></td>
        <td align="left"><label for="amputeeFee">$50.00</label></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input name="amputeeFee" type="number" id="amputeeFee" class="tblRight" size="10" value="0.00"/></td>
   </tr>

jquery

   <script>
   function changeFee(val) {
     $('#amputeeFee').val(), "$50.00";
        }
   </script>
```

Comment: `onchange="changeFee"` should be `onchange="changeFee(this.value)"`

Comment: Also `val()` is a getter.  `val(newValue)` is a setter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully functioning snippet. No jQuery required!

When the `onchange` event fires, it checks whether the checkbox was just checked or unchecked, and toggles the price accordingly. It can even be combined with all sorts of other checkboxes.

```js
function togglePrice(element,price){
  if(element.checked){
    document.getElementById("amputeeFee").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("amputeeFee").value) + price;
  }else{
    document.getElementById("amputeeFee").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("amputeeFee").value) - price;
  }
}
```

```html
<tr>
        <td><input name="amputeeGolfer" type="checkbox" id="amputeeGolfer" value="amputee" onchange="togglePrice(this,50);"/>
            <label for="amputeeGolfer">Amputee Golfer</label></td>
        <td align="left"><label for="amputeeFee">$50.00</label></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input name="amputeeFee" type="number" id="amputeeFee" class="tblRight" size="10" value="0"/></td>
   </tr>
```

It works perfectly and you can even set how much the checkbox adds to the cost!

Comment: @ScottA If this answer helped you, please consider clicking the [green check mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to accept the answer

Comment: This answer was close to what I need. I will have to figure a way to reformat the displayed results in a money form, ie, not 50 but $50.00. I haven't researched output formatting yet so I'm sure its possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can get closest tr `closest('tr')` to assure input in same row with check box and find input with name `find("input[name='amputeeFee']")` and change value for it.

```
function changeFee(val) {
   var amputeeFee = $(val).closest('tr').find("input[name='amputeeFee']");

   if($(val).prop("checked")){
       amputeeFee.val(50.00);
   }
   else{
      amputeeFee.val(0);
   }
}
```

```js
function changeFee(val) {
var amputeeFee = $(val).closest('tr').find("input[name='amputeeFee']");
//console.log(amp.length);
if($(val).prop("checked")){
   amputeeFee.val(50.00);
}
else{
   amputeeFee.val(0);
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
        <td><input name="amputeeGolfer" type="checkbox" id="amputeeGolfer" value="amputee" onchange="changeFee(this)"/>
            <label for="amputeeGolfer">Amputee Golfer</label></td>
        <td align="left"><label for="amputeeFee">$50.00</label></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input name="amputeeFee" type="number" id="amputeeFee" class="tblRight" size="10" value="0.00"/></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: This seemed to work well except (the big except) that I didn't mention in my original question that I was going to have multiple rows, each with their own "fees". The only way this works on subsequent rows is to have the prior row checked. I made some minor changes to the jquery to handle an unchecked event but am now stuck on how to make this happen whichever individual rows the user clicks. I'm trying to figure how to include the new code to this question but have not found a way. Perhaps a new question?

Comment: I was sleep while you comment, you can use $(val).prop("checked") like updated answer, new great day :)

Answer (score 0):

To call a JavaScript function like `changeFee(val)` in an HTML's element event, the funciton has to be called as the same in the script. As all functions in an HTML' event: `<element onclick="myFunction()">`, and not `<element onclick="myFunction">` beacuse it doesn't reconize it's a function in JavaScript.

Then the code will be:

```
<tr>
    <td><input name="amputeeGolfer" type="checkbox" id="amputeeGolfer" value="amputee" onchange="changeFee(this.value)"/>
        <label for="amputeeGolfer">Amputee Golfer</label></td>
    <td align="left"><label for="amputeeFee">$50.00</label></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input name="amputeeFee" type="number" id="amputeeFee" class="tblRight" size="10" value="0.00"/></td>
```